# JavaFX SceneBuilder Binding ObjectProperty

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new to using ObjectProperties in JavaFX SceneBuilder so I'm looking for some help.

I want to bind a color to a pane so the pane will be filled with this color.
Here's what I tried

```java
// Pane background colors
ObjectProperty<Paint> paneColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ObjectProperty<Background> paneBackground = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Background(new 

BackgroundFill(paneColor.get(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
ObjectProperty<Paint> paneBorderColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Paint.valueOf("#c9d4cc"));

controller.getBackgroundPane().backgroundProperty().bind(paneBackground);
controller.getBackgroundPane().setStyle("-fx-border-color: " + paneBorderColor.get());

public Paint getPaneColor() {
        return paneColor.get();
    }
    
    public void setPaneColor(Paint color) {
        this.paneColor.set(color);
    }
    
    public Paint getPaneBorderColor() {
        return this.paneBorderColor.get();
    }
    
    public void setPaneBorderColor(Paint color) {
        this.paneBorderColor.set(color);
    }
    
    public Background getPaneBackgroundColor() {
        return this.paneBackground.get();
    }
    
    public void setPaneBackgroundColor(Background background) {
        this.paneBackground.set(background);
    }
```

The colors don't show up on the pane, but their property fields show in the SceneBuilder editor. However, they don't change when I edit them via SceneBuilder.

Could someone please give me some clarification as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Everything works great now, but I want to bind a color to the border color of the pane. I tried this approach using a StringProperty that is bound to the styleproperty of the pane. It works, but I'm curious if there is a more efficient way (one where I could use the color picker in SceneBuilder and not have to code the width of the border using CSS).

Here is my code:

```java
StringProperty paneBorderColor = new SimpleStringProperty("#c9d4cc");

controller.getBackgroundPane().styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
"-fx-border-color: " + paneBorderColor.get() + "; -fx-border-width: 2px 0px 2px 0px", 
paneBorderColor));

public String getPaneBorderColor() {
    return this.paneBorderColor.get();
}
    
public void setPaneBorderColor(String color) {
    this.paneBorderColor.set(color);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no effect taking place when changing the color property in Scene Builder, then the binding is not correct. You can use `Bindings.createObjectBinding(...)`. Here is an example how it works:

*Edit:
Added example for border color and width.*

**Controller:**

```
package custom.control;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;

    private final ObjectProperty<Paint>
            backgroundColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(),
            borderColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final DoubleProperty
            borderWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        // Binding for background color:
        pane.backgroundProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
                        new Background(new BackgroundFill(backgroundColor.get(),
                                CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)),
                backgroundColor));

        // Binding for border color and width:
        pane.borderProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
                        new Border(new BorderStroke(borderColor.get(),
                                BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                                CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                                new BorderWidths(borderWidth.get()))),
                borderColor, borderWidth));
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> backgroundColorProperty() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> borderColorProperty() {
        return borderColor;
    }

    public DoubleProperty borderWidthProperty() {
        return borderWidth;
    }
}
```

**CustomPane:**

```
package custom.control;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomPane extends AnchorPane {

    private final ObjectProperty<Paint>
            backgroundColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.BLACK),
            borderColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.RED);

    private final DoubleProperty
            borderWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(3);

    public CustomPane() {
        super();

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("custom-pane.fxml"));

            Controller controller = new Controller();
            loader.setController(controller);

            Pane root = loader.load();
            this.getChildren().add(root);

            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(root, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(root, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(root, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(root, 0d);

            controller.backgroundColorProperty().bind(backgroundColor);

            controller.borderWidthProperty().bind(borderWidth);
            controller.borderColorProperty().bind(borderColor);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Paint getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> backgroundColorProperty() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(Paint backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor.set(backgroundColor);
    }

    public Paint getBorderColor() {
        return borderColor.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> borderColorProperty() {
        return borderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(Paint borderColor) {
        this.borderColor.set(borderColor);
    }

    public double getBorderWidth() {
        return borderWidth.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty borderWidthProperty() {
        return borderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(double borderWidth) {
        this.borderWidth.set(borderWidth);
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

**Scene Builder Preview:**

[image: Scene Builder Preview]

Comment: It works perfectly! I have another small question that relates to this topic, so please check the edit in the original post. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I just added an example for border color and border width.